# how to select rows from table or corresponding rows exist in subtable

Tags: sql

I am not sure how to get all the rows from the parent table that also exist in the child table.
For example,

parent table:

```
pid | description
1   | hi
2   | hello
3   | haha
4   | huhu
5   | hoho
```

child table

```
pid | cid
1   | 2
1   | 3
3   | 5
```

So, for pid1, we also see it in the child table with cid 2 and 3.
also, for pid3, we see it in the child table with cid 5.
I want to retrieve all the rows for example, where the search query is description = hi, it returns rows of pid 1, 2 and 3.
If pid is not in the child table, we just retrieve from parent table only.

Comment: So `pid:3` gets roped in because it's a grandchild? Otherwise I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from parent p
join child c on c.pid = p.pid
join parent t on t.pid = p.pid or t.pid = c.cid
where p.description = 'hi'
```

Comment: can you teach me how to modify it if I also want the rows even tho id is not in the child.

Comment: I am thinking of using LEFT OUTER JOIN child c on c.pid = p.pid part.
It looks like properly working on my sample but is it logically correct in your opinion?

Comment: @Crazy9 Please include the example and the expected result for this new case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
with cte as 
(
select pid,description from parent where description='hi'
)
select * from cte 
union
select parent.pid, parent.description from parent 
join child on
parent.pid=child.cid
join cte on
cte.pid=child.pid
```

See the result from [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u82vmgK6bYyYBEVsExML4Y/0).

The using of `UNION` is to ensure the selecting of required data rows from `parent` table even if the `parent.pid` value is not existed in `child.cid` column, i.e. `description='huhu'` in the provided dataset.